# Conditional probability with independent events

Tags: probability

Given two independent events A,B. 
Does the following equation hold?

P[(A & B) | C] = P[A|C]*P[B|C]

I assume it does because P[A & B] = P[A]P[B] or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Independence does not imply conditional independence. The first example that comes to my mind is  that of independent numbers of calls arriving at two call centres. But if there is a breakdown in the telephone lines they are not independent anymore. See also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence.

Comment: Make sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, let A be the event that you get Heads on a coin in your left hand, B the event that you get Heads on a coin in your right hand, and C the event that you get heads on at least one of the two coins.

Answer (score 1):

In general it does not. Independence of $A$ and $B$ are not enough to ensure this result.

Under the additional assumptions that $C$ is independent of $A$, of $B$ and of $A\land B $, then yes.

In that case we get:

$P(A \land B /C)= P(A \land B) = P(A) P(B) = P(A/C) P(B/C)$

It is easy to construct a counter-example where any one of the additional assumptions is not valid (while the other two are), in which case the equation will not hold, which I think will give you the definite answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known example of three events $A,B,C$ such that any two of them are independent but $P(A\cap B\cap C) \neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$. In this case the equation does not hold.